# Pushforward of a line bundle along a finite morphism of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism (a branched covering) of degree $n$ of smooth complex algebraic curves.

It is a known result that for any line bundle $L$ on $X$, the pushforward $f_* L$ is a vector bundle of rank $n$ (i.e. the pushforward sheaf of the sheaf of sections of $L$ is locally free and of rank $n$).

Could anyone give a reference for a simple proof of this result? I know it can be derived as a particular case of more general results, but I am interested in this simple case.

Comment: Being a vector bundle is a local property. So, restricting to open sets in $Y$, you may assume $L=\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: You need to assume that $f$ is finite FLAT morphism, otherwise this is not true. For instance, if $X = \mathbb{A}^2$, $Y = \mathbb{A}^2/\pm1$, and $f$ is the quotient morphism, then $f_*O_X$ is not locally free.

Comment: @Sasha Yes, but the OP assumed $X$ and $Y$ are smooth, so that $f:X\to Y$ is flat by Miracle Flatness.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: Right.